# Sending the cursor to a new line when window boundaries are exceeded in SFML?

Tags: c++, newline, sfml

I want to know if there is any way to move the line of text I am typing to the next line when I exceed the window width's boundaries in SFML? I am new to SFML but I can't get my head around it. I've tried a large portion of it for the past three hours but it moves to a new line then stuck on one line and I can't do anything with it. Any ideas? here is my code.

```
    #include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
int main(){
    srand(time(0));
    sf::Vector2i screenDimensions(800, 600);

    sf::RenderWindow window(sf::VideoMode(screenDimensions.x, screenDimensions.y), "My First SFML Game");

    sf::Texture pTexture;
    sf::Sprite playerImage;

    if (!pTexture.loadFromFile("Player.png"))
        window.setTitle("Couldn't load player image!");

    playerImage.setTexture(pTexture);

    sf::Font font;
    if (!font.loadFromFile("Sitka.ttc"))
        window.setTitle("Oops!");

    sf::String string;
    sf::Text text(string, font, 40);
    text.setColor(sf::Color(44, 127, 255));
    text.setStyle(sf::Text::Bold | sf::Text::Underlined);
    while (window.isOpen())
    {
        sf::Event event;

        while (window.pollEvent(event)){
            switch (event.type)
            {
            case sf::Event::Closed:
                window.close();
                break;
            case sf::Event::KeyPressed:
                if (event.key.code == sf::Keyboard::Escape){
                    window.close();
                    break;
            case sf::Event::TextEntered:
                if (event.text.unicode >= 32 && event.text.unicode <= 126) {
                    string += event.text.unicode;
                }
                else if (event.text.unicode == 8 && string.getSize() > 0)
                    string.erase(string.getSize() - 1, 1);
                text.setString(string);

                if (text.getLocalBounds().width > 800) {
                    if (event.text.unicode >= 32 && event.text.unicode <= 126) {
                        string.clear();
                        string += "\n";
                        string += event.text.unicode;
                        text.setString(string);
                    }
                    else if (event.text.unicode == 8 && string.getSize() > 0)
                        string.erase(string.getSize() - 1, 1);

                    }
                }
            }
        }

        window.draw(text);
        window.display();
        window.clear();
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

your problem is that *"sf::String::clear()"* deletes the whole string. But you only want to delete the last character of the string.

For this purpose, std::string (and sf::String) has a member function *"erase()"*.
With erase you can simply delete one character from the string. You want to delete the last character, which is at position *"string.getSize() - 1"* , so just change your line *"string.clear();"*  to *"string.erase(string.getSize() - 1);"*  and everything should work.

Comment: That's not what I'm asking. I'm asking how to move the cursor to the next line when it goes out of the global bounds of the width of the screen. Like this;

Text goes out of global bounds at exclamation point here !
New line starts here once exclamation point is reached

Answer (score 0):

**Problem**

When you call the string clear message, it causes all string characters to be removed, and hence the new line you created. So you are effectively repeating this process after you have entered one line. Which is why it appears to be getting 'stuck' on the same line.

**Solution**

If you want to keep the desired effect (clear the original line and move onto the next) you could simply keep track of the line number and enter that amount of newlines each time.

Code:

```
int lineNumber(0);

//....

if (event.text.unicode >= 32 && event.text.unicode <= 126) {
    ++lineNumber; // move onto the next line
    string.clear();
    for (int i(0); i < lineNumber; ++i)
        string += "\n";
    string += event.text.unicode;
    text.setString(string);
}
```